# How to set height of UILabel to contain an NSString with variable length, in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I need to create a UITableView in which UITableViewCell contains two UILabel, one of them should fit height to its content NSString. The width of the UILabel is fixed, and the number of lines is set to 0. How can I get the height ? 
I see code like this:

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(300, 9999);
NSString *myString = @"This is a long string which wraps";
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
CGSize myStringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:myFont 
                           constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
lineBreakMode:self.myLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

but the result is: there is only one character in a line of UILabel.
Why cannot I use this method? Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, so just clarifying, you want the label's height to be dynamic based on the amount of text?  And since it is in a UITableView, the row height also needs to be dynamic?

Comment: Are you also resizing the label frame? You have two optoins: using the autoresizing mask so the label expands with the cell itself, or setting the frame by hand.

Comment: for obuseme, yes. for Ricard, yes too.now I found the answer. calculate for height of the content string is needed in both cellForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath. thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get it working, code in my project:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"shopmessage";
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

UILabel* content = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:11];
UILabel* date = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:12];
NSDictionary* msg = [ _msglist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString* type = [[msg objectForKey:@"msgtype"] intValue] == 0 ? @"我:":@"店家:";
[content setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",type,[msg objectForKey:@"sendmsg"]]];
[date setText:[msg objectForKey:@"sendtime"]];

CGSize contentsize = [content.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 1000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
//    content.frame.size = contentsize;
content.frame = CGRectMake(content.frame.origin.x, content.frame.origin.y, contentsize.width, contentsize.height);

[date setText:[msg objectForKey:@"sendtime"]];
//    date.frame.origin = CGPointMake(date.frame.origin.x, content.frame.origin.y + content.frame.size.height + 10);
date.frame = CGRectMake(date.frame.origin.x, content.frame.origin.y + content.frame.size.height, date.frame.size.width, date.frame.size.height);
return cell;
```

}

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary* msg = [ _msglist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString* text =[msg objectForKey:@"sendmsg"];
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 1000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];

    return size.height + 30;
}
```

reference:[Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2342307?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *str = @"This is a very very long string which wraps";
    CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size.height + 10;
}
```

Comment: your code is the same with what I post in the question. and I have test   it, same result too. thanks anyway

Comment: this should be work. in function cellForRowAtIndexPath , this should be calculated too.